# Android Studio: Execution fails when I add SignalR client library

Tags: android, android-studio, signalr

I have downloaded signalr client library from https://github.com/SignalR/java-client. On build it generated jar files.

When I add the jar files to my project, the project builds but when I try to run I get the error message below:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Previously I followed the tutorial on https://whathecode.wordpress.com/2014/03/20/getting-started-with-the-java-signalr-sdk/ and downloaded jar files from https://www.mediafire.com/?8qun6hbs3onnbbl. Those jar files were working fine.

However I needed the WebSocket transport protocol which were implemented in the latest version.

I am not sure if removal of previous jar files causing any issues.

Gradle scripts:

- signalr-client-sdk

  ```
  apply plugin: 'java'
  dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.2'
  compile 'org.java-websocket:java-websocket:1.3.1'
  }
  ```

-signalr-client-sdk-android

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 8
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
compile project(':signalr-client-sdk')
```

}

-My project

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.eb5.uvexa.uvexadriver"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    debug {
        debuggable true
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
dexOptions
        {
           preDexLibraries=false
        }
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
compile files('libs/gson-2.2.2.jar')
compile files('libs/mail.jar')
compile files('libs/activation.jar')
compile files('libs/additionnal.jar')
compile files('libs/signalr-client-sdk.jar')
compile files('libs/signalr-client-sdk-android.jar')
}
```

I tried clean and rebuild, restarted the pc and also Invalidate option in Android Studio.

I am using windows10 and Android Studio(64). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please go to my github https://github.com/ngocchung/SimpleSignalRClient. However, looks like that  WebSocket transport protocol still not yet supported

Comment: This version does not have WebSocket support. But the new one has.